# startActivityForResult gives exception

Tags: android, fingerprint

I am new to android can someone help me please, following is the code i tried to run for scanning the fingerprint but it gives an error whenever i click the button it says force to close what should i do help me please.

```
Intent fingerPrintCaptureImageIntent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                fingerPrintCaptureImageIntent
                        .putExtra("source", "registration");
                // fingerPrintCaptureImageIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                // fingerPrintCaptureImageIntent.setComponent(new
                // ComponentName("com.integratedbiometrics.SimpleScan",
                // "com.integratedbiometrics.SimpleScan.SimpleScanActivity"));
                PackageManager packageManager = getActivity()
                        .getPackageManager();
                List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager
                        .queryIntentActivities(fingerPrintCaptureImageIntent, 0);

                boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;
                if (isIntentSafe) {
                    try {
                            startActivityForResult( fingerPrintCaptureImageIntent, Constants.FINGER_PRINT_REQUEST_CODE_FOR_REGISTRATION);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("TAG",e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.i("No Such Activity Found",
                            "No Such Activity Found To Open.");
                }
```

And the onActivityResult method is :

```
  if (requestCode == Constants.FINGER_PRINT_REQUEST_CODE_FOR_REGISTRATION
                && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data.hasExtra("cancel")) {
                // do nothing ...
            } else if (data.hasExtra("file_name")) {
                String fileName = data.getStringExtra("file_name");
                ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(
                        R.id.fingerprintTakenInfoText)).setText(fileName + "");
                if (fileName != null) {
                    try {
                        String fingerData = Utility
                                .ReadFingerDataFromExternalStorage(fileName);
                        parentActivity.registrationEntity.fingerPrints = fingerData;
                        fingerPrintDataFileName = fileName;
                        ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(
                                R.id.fingerprintTakenInfoText))
                                .setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(
                                        R.color.green));
                        ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(
                                R.id.fingerprintTakenInfoText))
                                .setText("Finger print taken.");
                    } catch (Exception exp) {
                        ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(
                                R.id.fingerprintTakenInfoText))
                                .setText("Reading finger print data from file failed.");
                    }
                }
            }
```

On Calling my App secugen , I have got exception . The error is 
[image]
My SecuGen app is crashed . Can you help me ?

Comment: Post your logcat error trace.

Comment: No error in logcat .

Comment: How can I see error in logcat ?

Comment: try printing your stack trace in your catch block. like this **exp.printStackTrace();**

Comment: Boss , can you see my code and tell me how can I  solve this error ?

Comment: Please show your logcat stacktrace, then only people can try to help you.

Comment: How can I see message in logcat stacktrace ?

Comment: in a prompt command, run "adb logcat"